# How to stop a destructor from being called on a stack allocated object?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a union-like class with a member that may or may not be garbage depending on a boolean flag also set in that same class.

Obviously, I do not want that garbage to be destructed when my class goes out of scope. How to prevent a class member from being destructed?

I know this could be achieved with pointers and dynamically allocated memory, but I am looking for a more simple solution.

```
class MyContainer {
    bool has_child;
    MyChild child;

public:
    MyContainer(MyChild child) { this->has_child = true; this->child = child; }
    MyContainer() { this->has_child = false; }

    ~MyContainer() {
        if (!this->has_child) {
            // What to do here?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just make destructor do nothing if it is on the stack.

Comment: You cannot prevent a class from being destroyed when it goes out of scope. This is fundamental to C++. Your problem is your overall class design, and not the destructor.

Comment: @Incomputable That will destruct `child` though, will it not?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Is dynamically allocated memory the only way to go then?

Comment: The solution is to make sure that the member can be safely destroyed even if it's "garbage".

Comment: @JeroenBollen, yes. So you will need to handle that problem as well. But at least it will prevent stack corruption :)

Comment: The `child` will be default constructed anyway, so it is not just "garbage".

Comment: Well, that's one option. The other option, I suspect is to make your classes [compliant with the Rule Of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), which I suspect is your real problem. If your class is compliant with the Rule Of Three, it doesn't matter whether it's on stack, or dynamically allocated.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I suppose the question was badly worded. It doesn't matter if the container is on the stack, for there to be an issue here. I suppose the real issue is that child is not behind a pointer.

Comment: You should seek to get rid of the `MyContainer()` constructor. It apparently permits construction of semantically invalid objects.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Very funny and all, but that doesn't actually provide a solution.

Comment: @JeroenBollen: Why? It is the long-term solution. This entire class design is highly defective, and allowing the construction of invalid instances seems to be the root of all problems.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The code works just as bad with the class as without it. Getting rid of it might be part of a solution, but it certainly isn't one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) (since C++17), which won't cause dynamic memory allocation. e.g.

```
class MyContainer {
    bool has_child;
    std::optional<MyChild> child;

public:
    MyContainer(MyChild child) : child(child) { this->has_child = true; }
    MyContainer() { this->has_child = false; }

    ~MyContainer() { /* nothing special need to do */ }
};
```

BTW: The member `has_child` could be replaced by `std::optional::has_value()`.

Comment: Is there anything similar < C++17?

Comment: @JeroenBollen [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)? I'm not familiar with Boost, you might check the document carefully.

Comment: I settled with `std::unique_ptr`. I'll be happy to switch to `std::optional` once C++17 is finished though.

Comment: @JeroenBollen: If you can freely choose your compiler, then you can easily become an early adopter of C++17 features if you really want to. For example, Visual C++ 2017 supports `std::optional` and many other C++17 features with the `/std:c++latest` flag.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that sure I would recommend it, but you can use placement new in a correctly sized array to do that.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>

struct MyChild {
    ~MyChild() { std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl; }
};

class MyContainer {
    bool drop;
    char arr[sizeof(MyChild)];
    MyChild *child;

public:
    MyContainer(bool drop)
        : drop{drop}, child{::new(&arr) MyChild{}}
    {}

    ~MyContainer() {
        if (drop) { child->~MyChild(); }
    }
};

void f() {
    std::cout << "f" << std::endl;
    MyContainer cont{true};
}

void g() {
    std::cout << "g" << std::endl;
    MyContainer cont{false};
}

int main() {
    f();
    g();
}
```

As you can see, destructor of `MyChild` is called only within `f`. Within `MyContainer`, whenever you want to access the instance of `MyChild`, you can do that through the `child` data member. And, of course, it's not dynamically allocated.